# Python odeint weird solution

Tags: python, odeint

The problem is the hydrogen atom in classical mechanics. Solution should be an elliptic revolution around the center. However I get a result which doesn't make sense at all (see figure). Checked the equations and physics zillion times. What is the problem here? Something related with the odeint function? Turned out to be a real bugger for me :-((

Here is the code:

```
c1 = -1710.82735072
x0 = 0.0
y0 = 1.0
vx0 = 15.0
vy0 = 0.0
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import *
def deriv(z,t):   
   return array([z[1],c1*z[0]/((z[0]**2+z[2]**2)**1.5),z[3],c1*z[2]/((z[0]**2+z[2]**2)**1.5)])
time = linspace(0,0.06,1000)
zinit = array([x0,vx0,y0,vy0])
z = odeint(deriv,zinit,time)
figure()
plot(z[:,0],z[:,2])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Here what it gives, the revolution is not around the center
[image: Here what it gives, the revolution is not around the center]

If you plot the velocities (z[1],z[3]) vs time etc. they are also messed up

Comment: It would be nice if you add a link to the formula and label the axis

Comment: what if you provide tha jacobian (should be possible with your system).

Comment: Did you mix up z[:,2] and z[:,3] ? Because the last one (the orbital ?) is centered